# Unresolved reference: ExoPlayerFactory in ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance and Type mismatch: inferred type is Uri! but MediaItem was expected in

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, exoplayer-media-item

after updating to the latest build version of ExoPlayer i.e "2.18.1",
ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance showing unresolved reference Error,

Want to reformat this  Initialize Function to the latest version of exoplayer
without changing its Logic

getting obscured errors in function

```
 private fun initializeExoPlayer(soundFile: String): ExoPlayer {
        // create the player
        val exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(
            DefaultRenderersFactory(this), DefaultTrackSelector()
        )

        // load the media source
        val dataSource = DefaultDataSourceFactory(this,
            Util.getUserAgent(this, this.getString(R.string.app_name)))
        val mediaSource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSource)
            .createMediaSource(Uri.parse("asset:///$soundFile"))

        // load the media
        Log.d("MAIN", "loading $soundFile")
        exoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource)
        // loop indefinitely
        exoPlayer.repeatMode = Player.REPEAT_MODE_ALL

        return exoPlayer
    }
```

the errors are

1. Unresolved reference: ExoPlayerFactory
2. Type mismatch: inferred type is Uri! but MediaItem was expected
   in

```
     .createMediaSource(Uri.parse("asset:///$soundFile"))
```

3. Variable expected in

```
exoPlayer.repeatMode = Player.REPEAT_MODE_ALL
```

ScreenShot  [image: ScreenShot]

gradle:

```
    // ExoPlayer
    api "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.18.1"
    api "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.18.1"
    api "com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-mediasession:2.18.1"
```

**TRIED**
after searching multiple times
changed the following function into ->

```
  private fun initializeExoPlayer(soundFile: String): ExoPlayer {

        // create the player
        val exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(this).build()

        // load the media source
        val dataSource = DefaultDataSourceFactory(this,
                Util.getUserAgent(this, this.getString(R.string.app_name)))

        val firstAudioUri = Uri.parse("assets:///$soundFile")
        val mediaSource = MediaItem.fromUri(firstAudioUri)

        // load the media
        Log.d("MAIN", "loading $soundFile")
        exoPlayer.addMediaItem(mediaSource)
        exoPlayer.prepare()
        // loop indefinitely
        exoPlayer.repeatMode = Player.REPEAT_MODE_ALL

        return exoPlayer
    }
```

all the indicated Errors were gone but
no media is playing and Variable 'dataSource' is never used

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: tried Documentation but Exoplayer Documentation is very hard to understand

Comment: getting the exact same error after updating... did you find a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i Tried this, and its working fine now.

```
   private fun initializeExoPlayer(soundFile: String): ExoPlayer {


        // create the player
        val trackSelector = DefaultTrackSelector(this)
        val exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(this).setTrackSelector(trackSelector).build()

        // load the media source
        val dataSource = DefaultDataSource.Factory(this)

        val mediaSource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSource)
            .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(Uri.parse("asset:///$soundFile")))

        // load the media
        Log.d("MAIN", "loading $soundFile")
        exoPlayer.setMediaSource(mediaSource)
        exoPlayer.prepare()
      
        // loop indefinitely
        exoPlayer.repeatMode = Player.REPEAT_MODE_ALL

        return exoPlayer
    }
```